# Getting rid of whitespace in a dictionary

Tags: c#, idictionary

I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictGenSubs = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

How can I make sure that there is no whitespace in any of the records of the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking only about the strings in the list.

To achieve that goal, you can use this code:

```
dictGenSubs = dictGenSubs.ToDictionary(
                  x => x.Key,
                  x => x.Value
                        .Select(x => x.Replace(" ", string.Empty))
                        .ToList());
```

This creates a new dictionary with new lists as the values of the dictionary. Each string in each list will be adjusted before being added to the new list.

A more efficient approach would be to update the existing dictionary and the existing lists:

```
foreach(var list in dictGenSubs.Values)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
        list[i] = list[i].Replace(" ", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new dictionary?

Comment: `Trim()` only removes leading and trailing whitespace, better to use `x.Replace(" ", string.empty)`

Comment: @svick: Because that's the only way this can be written using LINQ. Please see the updated answer for a more efficient implementation.

Comment: @LelloThree: I understood his question like he doesn't want to have leading or trailing whitespace. Re-reading it I agree that this isn't stated anywhere.

Comment: I prefer the non-LINQ method, much more understandable IMO.

Comment: @ken2k: Agreed, me to. But nowadays, everyone wants to do everything with LINQ. So, if there is a more or less reasonable way to do it with LINQ, I provide it.

Comment: Linq has it's place, it'often more understandable than nested loops but it's not the best tool to modify something or use indexes heavily. Then it becomes inefficient and clumsy.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I know that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean any whitespace at all in any of the strings in each value? Here's a succinctly inefficient way with LINQ:

```
bool hasWhitespace = dictGenSubs.SelectMany(kv => kv.Value)
       .Any(s => s.Any(char.IsWhiteSpace));
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that he don't want to know if there's a white-space but he wants to get rid of them(see title).

Comment: Yes, well removing the whitespace before adding them would seem the most logical. Otherwise Daniel's second approach.